# How can I make an statement to output different things based on other cells

Tags: google-sheets

I'm writing a spreadsheet for a planning of some sort. It is about a band with multiple musicians on sometimes the same instruments. I've made two sheets. One for the musicians to let them show when they'll be present, while the other has to make an overview of all musicians present on certain dates.

I've already made an if statement to show when one of them is present, which would look like this in simple code:

```
if(B2)
print("Eric")
```

What I actually would want is an if statement to show when they are both present. In simple code it would look like this:

```
if(B2)
print("Eric")

if(B2 && C2)
print(", ")

if(C2)
print("Frank")
```

Really simplified.

I've made an example spreadsheet to show what I've already got. Here it is:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17gyoh5NUdiUWB_Nq0w3FAc1OsWQygzRYd_kzm0ijdJA/edit?usp=sharing

So what I would like to see with input as: B3=TRUE, C3=TRUE.

in sheet2 it should then show in B3: Eric, Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Sample formulas:

Please put 1st and 2nd formula to "B3" and "C3" of Sheet2, respectively.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", "; TRUE; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Sheet1!B3:C3=TRUE; Sheet1!$B$2:$C$2;)))
```

and

```
=TEXTJOIN(", "; TRUE; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(Sheet1!D3:G3=TRUE; Sheet1!$D$2:$G$2;)))
```

- Retrieve values that the checkbox is checked using `IF` and `ARRAYFORMULA()`.
- Join the retrieved values using `TEXTJOIN()`.

#### Result:

For example, when B3, C3, E3 and F3 of Sheet1 are checked, Sheet2 becomes as follows.

[image]

#### References:

- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.